# Obtaining a Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have to solve this question:
Find the Laurent expansion for $f(z)={z \over z^2+1}$ in the region |z-3|>2.

I know I have to write f(z) in terms of z-3 and I have already done that: 
${0.5 \over (z-3)+3+i} + {0.5 \over (z-3)+3-i}$

But I don't know how to continue

Comment: Add your atempts and what you have already done to your question thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the condition is $|z-3|>2$?

Comment: Yeah, those are the conditions